# Decrypting server entries in custom maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I'm trying to write a custom maven-2 plugin and can't seem to find any documentation on reading the settings.xml, and decrypting server entries.

I looked around at some maven dependencies such as `maven-settings` and `maven-settings-builder` (both version 3.0.3, which i assume it for maven 3 as i have a problem with a method not found exception on `Server.clone()`).

`maven-settings:2.2.1` has the ability to load the settings up (painfully, you have to provide a path to the settings.xml - is there a factory method to just use the default ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml?), but i can't find the decrypt API (like the one that exists in 3.0.3):

```
DefaultMavenSettingsBuilder builder = new DefaultMavenSettingsBuilder();
Settings settings = builder.buildSettings(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.m2/settings.xml"));
settings.getServer("id").getPassword(); 
// i get the encrypted String "{gsfdGJHv69}"
```

Anyway, i'm specifically looking for guidance on how to (with maven 2.2.1):

1. Load the user's settings.xml into an `org.apache.maven.Settings` object without having to specify the full path
2. Decrypt a particular named Server entry in the settings.xml file (like you can do in 3.0.3 with maven-settings-builder:3.0.3 `DefaultSettingsDecryptor` class)

All within the execute method of my custom `AbstractMojo` implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is always the way, just spending a few more minutes searching and hunting through the source, and answer presents itself...

(**Updated: See @ST-DDT's answer for v3.3 maven**)

Digging through the source for how 3.0.3 does decryption i stumbled across the SecDispatcher interface and DefaultSecDispatcher implementation. A quick google on that term brought me to this article:

- http://ambientideas.com/blog/index.php/2009/08/encrypted-scm-passwords-in-maven/

Which details how to acquire the SecDispatcher through the plexus container. So now i have a way to decrypt, now i just need a prettier way to get the settings, and this is similar to the acquisition of the SecDispatcher - using the container:

```
Settings settings = ( (MavenSettingsBuilder) container.lookup(MavenSettingsBuilder.ROLE) ).buildSettings();

SecDispatcher secDispatcher = (SecDispatcher) container.lookup(SecDispatcher.ROLE, "maven")

String password = secDispatcher.decrypt(settings.getServer("id").getPassword());
```

Final gotcha was a problem with the `maven-plugin-api` and `maven-settings` pom dependencies needed to (obvious after the fact) provided scope, so they didn't cause ClassCastExceptions between the bundled and runtime container versions

Comment: This no longer worked for me: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.DefaultSecDispatcher$__sisu10 cannot be cast to org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecDispatcher (Maven  3.3.9)

Answer (score 5):

This github project let's you decode the passwords in a setttings.xml file

https://github.com/jelmerk/maven-settings-decoder

Answer (score 1):

I was able to decrypt the password using the inbuild `settingsDecrypter`.

```
@Component
private SettingsDecrypter settingsDecrypter;

SettingsDecryptionRequest decryptionRequest = new DefaultSettingsDecryptionRequest(possibleProxy);
SettingsDecryptionResult decryptionResult = this.settingsDecrypter.decrypt(decryptionRequest);
Proxy proxy = decryptionResult.getProxy();
```

Tested with Maven 3.3.9. Works with `proxies` and `servers` alike.